Any advice to model this crown?
I am trying to recreate this crown in Blender, but I am getting no results. The hard part is the Middle part of the crown, the extruded part, and the bottom part that has those ridges on it.
Any advice? Would really appreciate it!

What have you tried?

I tried using boolean to cut into my object, but that doesn't work out very well, then I tried making it from a sphere, which also didn't work out. I was thinking maybe to photograph the crown and maybe use a program to make me a model, but I don't know if that would work

You could do photogrammetry, but that would produce messy geometry requiring manual remodeling anyway and you would need to coat it with something not reflective first and it's really small, so that might not work well. If you can, taking more reference photographs might help a bit. I think best thing would be to watch some modelling tutorials and get more familiar with modelling tools.

It needs a lengthy tutorial to answer in full... You should count the radially symmetrical segments and work on only one peace with array modifier repeating that peace around. Work with as little geometry as possible and subdivision surface modifier. You should think in terms of topology here - where do you need edge loops in order to make the forms. Importing some reference image to Blender for proportions would be a good idea. Starting from a cylinder or sphere should work.

Create a segment of your object:

Array it:

Give it a Simple Deform modifier (Bend mode, 360° on Z):

